# Allauth authentication on homepage not working

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

To allow Django's allauth to work on my homepage, I copied the allauth HTML for the login and signup forms to my own base.html (The login form can be seen [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/templates/account/login.html#L36)).

So this successfully renders the form and its fields on my homepage. However, when I click submit on the login form, it just redirects me to allauth's /accounts/login URL, which renders the same form. Only after that does submitting the form work. It's the same with the signup form when I submit the signup form on my homepage, it redirects me to /accounts/signup and then the signup works after submitting again. How can I make the login/signup work initially from my homepage?

My urls and views:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.boxes_view, name='news'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def boxes_view(request):
   search = request.GET.get('search')
   posts = Post.objects.all().filter(category=1).order_by('-date')
   if search:
      posts = posts.filter(Q(title__icontains=search)|Q(content__icontains=search))
   else:
      posts = Post.objects.all().filter(category=1).order_by('-date')

   context = {'posts': posts,}
   return render(request, 'polls.html', context)
```

**base.html**

```
...

{% load i18n %}
<form class="login" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
<div class="loginWrapper">
    <div class="loginNested">
    <div class="loginBox">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}
  <a class="button secondaryAction" href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">{% trans "Forgot Password?" %}</a>
  <button class="primaryAction" type="submit">{% trans "Sign In" %}</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>

...
```

Comment: Post your urls.py here, then we can help you.

Comment: urls.py and views.py added

Comment: Where are the view and URL from which you are rendering login.html form ??

Comment: I'm not rendering login.html, I just copied the login.html code to my own base.html. And the polls.html being rendered in the view extends base.html.

Comment: You dont need to copy  login.html into your base.html code. Just use the url on which the submit button redirects you to login into your project.

Comment: That has the same outcome, just redirects me to /accounts/login. The url which the submit button redirects is "{% url 'account_login' %}"

Comment: you still haven't posted your template

Comment: It's just the code in the link I posted (login.html). But I added it in my edit.